# How to speed up python's 'turtle' function and stop it freezing at the end

Tags: python, graphics, draw, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have written a turtle program in python, but there are two problems.

1. It goes way too slow for larger numbers, I was wonder how I can speed up turtle.
2. It freezes after it finishes and when clicked on, says 'not responding'

This is my code so far:

```
import turtle

#Takes user input to decide how many squares are needed
f=int(input("How many squares do you want?"))
c=int(input("What colour would you like? red = 1, blue = 2 and green =3"))
n=int(input("What background colour would you like? red = 1, blue = 2 and green =3"))

i=1

x=65

#Draws the desired number of squares.
while i < f:
    i=i+1
    x=x*1.05
    print ("minimise this window ASAP")
    if c==1:
        turtle.pencolor("red")
    elif c==2:
        turtle.pencolor("blue")
    elif c==3:
        turtle.pencolor("green")
    else:
        turtle.pencolor("black")
    if n==1:
        turtle.fillcolor("red")
    elif n==2:
        turtle.fillcolor("blue")
    elif n==3:
        turtle.fillcolor("green")
    else:
        turtle.fillcolor("white")
    turtle.bk(x)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.bk(x)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.bk(x)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.bk(x)
    turtle.rt(90)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.rt(9)
    turtle.down()
```

By the way: I am on version 3.2!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. Set `turtle.speed("fastest")`.
2. Use the `turtle.mainloop()` functionality to do work without screen refreshes.
3. Disable screen refreshing with `turtle.tracer(0, 0)` then at the end do `turtle.update()`

Comment: If you are rolling with a newer version of turtle the turtle object has no tracer attribute. You have to set the tracer attribute for the Screen object instead.

Comment: What's the fastest it can go while keeping animation visible?

Comment: @HenrikSommerland I'm not sure which version you were referring to, but all versions I've used in the past few years have `tracer` on `turtle` as well as on screen.

Answer (score 23):

**Python turtle goes very slowly because screen refreshes are performed after every modification is made to a turtle.**

You can disable screen refreshing until all the work is done, then paint the screen, it will eliminate the millisecond delays as the screen furiously tries to update the screen from every turtle change.

**For example:**

```
import turtle
import random
import time
screen = turtle.Screen()

turtlepower = []

turtle.tracer(0, 0)
for i in range(1000):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.goto(random.random()*500, random.random()*1000)
    turtlepower.append(t)

for i in range(1000):
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.update()

time.sleep(3)
```

This code makes a thousand turtles at random locations, and displays the picture in about 200 milliseconds.

Had you not disabled screen refreshing with `turtle.tracer(0, 0)` command, it would have taken several minutes as it tries to refresh the screen 3000 times.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay

Answer (score 3):

For reference, turtle being slow is an existing problem.
Even with speed set to max, turtle can take quite a long time on things like fractals.
Nick ODell reimplemented turtle for speed here: [Hide Turtle Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236879/hide-turtle-window)

```
import math

class UndrawnTurtle():
def __init__(self):
    self.x, self.y, self.angle = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    self.pointsVisited = []
    self._visit()

def position(self):
    return self.x, self.y

def xcor(self):
    return self.x

def ycor(self):
    return self.y

def forward(self, distance):
    angle_radians = math.radians(self.angle)

    self.x += math.cos(angle_radians) * distance
    self.y += math.sin(angle_radians) * distance

    self._visit()

def backward(self, distance):
    self.forward(-distance)

def right(self, angle):
    self.angle -= angle

def left(self, angle):
    self.angle += angle

def setpos(self, x, y = None):
    """Can be passed either a tuple or two numbers."""
    if y == None:
        self.x = x[0]
        self.y = x[1]
    else:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    self._visit()

def _visit(self):
    """Add point to the list of points gone to by the turtle."""
    self.pointsVisited.append(self.position())

# Now for some aliases. Everything that's implemented in this class
# should be aliased the same way as the actual api.
fd = forward
bk = backward
back = backward
rt = right
lt = left
setposition = setpos
goto = setpos
pos = position

ut = UndrawnTurtle()
```