# Is there a delay moving between libraries in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So recently I decided to write a program to draw the mandelbrot set using turtle, and it works very well, except for one thing; it's quite slow, and it slows down as it draws. The way it draws is, if I remember correctly, as follows:

```
def drawpoint(x,y,colour):
    t.color(colour)
    t.setpos(x,y)
    t.down()
    t.forward(1)
    t.up()
```

and the program in general calculates the point (using `math` (specifically its trigonometry) and its colour and then draws it.

I can't work out why it's so slow, because it's not exactly an astonishing set of calculations. I'm fairly sure it's to do with `turtle`, and I was wondering if:

a) Python is slowed down by moving between `math` and `turtle` 
b) Turtle slows down as you draw more points 
c) Something else entirely

Is it any of these, and if so, how can I speed it up?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: There are multiple ways to make turtle faster: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16120087/380038

Comment: Turtle is designed to draw lines (and arcs), it's not very efficient at drawing pixels. If you want speed take a look at PIL for generating images, and you can display the generated image using Tkinter. FWIW, Turtle uses Tkinter to perform the actual drawing operations.

Comment: No, 'switching' between modules is not a thing. Everything is just objects on the heap, and modules let you load objects in groups as well as managed your namespaces, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give a clock value to ***quite slow***, I have to make assumptions.  (And I don't disagree with PM 2Ring that turtle.py may not be your best choice for this purpose.) I wrote a mandelbrot program, using generic turtle operations, which took nearly an hour to draw the 320 x 240 image below.  However, with a few turtle optimizations, I was able to get that down to just over a minute.  And there may be room to do better (see further below.)  Specific optimizations:

- Maximize the turtle drawing speed via `turtle.speed("fastest")`
- Use `screen.tracer(0, 0)` and `screen.update()` to do the bulk of the
  drawing offscreen.  In my code below, I update on each
  vertical slice of the image so you can see still its progress but
  don't delay for each individual pixel to be drawn.
- I found *stamping* my pixels to be more efficient than your
  `forward(1)` approach.  This isn't intuitive as stamping keeps track
  of the stamps and does a bunch of polygon operations but it still
  times out better.  This many be because it avoids the pen up and down
  operations.
- Make the turtle invisible either from creation using
  `turtle = Turtle(visible=False)` or later via `turtle.hideturtle()`.
  No need to waste time drawing the turtle itself for every pixel.
- Turn off *undo*.  (In the case of stamping, you can't turn it off
  due to a bug in turtle.py, but) in general, if you're drawing lots and
  don't plan to undo you, can `turtle.setundobuffer(None)` to
  turn off this feature and not store every operation in a buffer.
- As with any speed optimized program, avoid doing anything at runtime
  that you can do ahead -- waste lots of space doing so if needed.
  Avoid doing things at runtime that are redundant.  In my example
  below, I tried to minimize time spent on setting colors by
  precomputing the color values and avoiding `turtle.color(...)` if the
  pen color is already set to the correct color.

[image]

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COORDINATES = (-2.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 320, 240

colors = {i: ((i & 0b1111) << 4, (i & 0b111) << 5, (i & 0b11111) << 3) for i in range(2 ** 5)}

def mandelbrot(turtle, minimum_x, minimum_y, maximum_x, maximum_y, iterations, width, height):

    step_x, step_y = (maximum_x - minimum_x) / width, (maximum_y - minimum_y) / height

    real = minimum_x

    current_color = 0

    while real < maximum_x:

        imaginary = minimum_y

        while imaginary < maximum_y:

            color = 0

            c, z = complex(real, imaginary), 0j

            for i in range(iterations):
                if abs(z) >= 4.0:
                    color = i & 31
                    break

                z = z * z + c

            if color != current_color:
                turtle.color(colors[color])
                current_color = color

            turtle.setpos(real, imaginary)
            turtle.stamp()
            imaginary += step_y

        screen.update()
        real += step_x

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.setworldcoordinates(*COORDINATES)
screen.colormode(255)
screen.tracer(0, 0)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed("fastest")
turtle.setundobuffer(1)  # unfortunately setundobuffer(None|0) broken for turtle.stamp()

turtle.begin_poly()
# Yes, this is an empty polygon but produces a dot -- I don't know if this works on all platforms
turtle.end_poly()

screen.register_shape("pixel", turtle.get_poly())
turtle.shape("pixel")
turtle.up()

mandelbrot(turtle, *COORDINATES, 31, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

screen.exitonclick()
```

An unresolved issue is, as you noted, it slows down as draws.  It only takes 15 seconds to draw the first 2/3rds of the above image, the last third takes a minute.  I tried to find a reason but nothing so far.  An interesting twist is that the last 5% of the drawing speeds back up.