# draw a circles target using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

[image: Circles]

This my program using `turtle` to draw the circle target:

```
import turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)

for radius in range(100, 200, 10):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)
```

The code makes a moving curve, but I want the circle to be drawn at once.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119991/how-to-speed-up-pythons-turtle-function-and-stop-it-freezing-at-the-end?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: If you don't want animation, you can use `turtle.speed(0)` to make drawing happen instantly.

Comment: See example here: https://repl.it/@haakenlid/Turtletarget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `circle()` method draws a circle, but the `dot()` method stamps one out.  However, the `dot()` method doesn't have a separate line and fill concept and tends to overwrite itself, so we have to handle it carefully:

```
import turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.dot(radius + 2, 'black')
    turtle.dot(radius, 'white')

for radius in range(200, 0, -40):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Alternatively, we could stamp out circular cursors ourselves:

```
import turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.shapesize(radius)
    turtle.stamp()

turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.color('black', 'white')

for radius in range(10, 0, -2):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

But this doesn't produce as pleasing a result:

[image]

Of course, we can always cheat and use `turtle.speed('fastest')`, or better yet, turn tracing off altogether:

```
import turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius, steps=90)

turtle.tracer(False)

for radius in range(20, 120, 20):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.tracer(True)

turtle.mainloop()
```

But the result still won't look as nice as the `turtle.dot()` approach, even if you bump up the `steps` parameter of `turtle.circle()`:

[image]

> for the first code how to add an arrow on the top of each curve, one
>   at down of each curve?

This is easier done modifying my third example as we can more easily draw semicircles and stamp the cursor.  I'm using a custom cursor for arrow alignment across circles purposes:

```
import turtle

def origin_circle(turtle, radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-radius)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.circle(radius, extent=180, steps=45)
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.circle(radius, extent=180, steps=45)

turtle.addshape("pointer", ((0, 0), (5, -4), (0, 4), (-5, -4)))
turtle.shape("pointer")

turtle.tracer(False)

for idx, radius in enumerate(range(20, 120, 20), start=0):
    origin_circle(turtle, radius)

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.tracer(True)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: for the first code
how to add an arrow on the top of each curve, one at down of each curve?

Comment: @ShAlzoubi, I'd need to see an example as I don't understand your description.

Comment: @ShAlzoubi, I've added an example of such.

Comment: can we change the direction of the arrows to be clockwise!!

Comment: @ShAlzoubi, yes.  Definitely.

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle
ab=turtle.Turtle()
ab.speed(0)
import turtle

def zielscheibe(ringe=10):
    if ringe<1 or ringe>1000:
        ab.write('Bitte eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 1000 eingeben')
        return
    ab.pu()
    ab.goto(300,0)
    ab.seth(90)
    x=300/ringe
    for n in range(ringe):
        ab.pd()
        if n ==ringe-1:
            ab.color('black')
        elif n %2==0:
            ab.color('red')
        else:
            ab.color('white')
        ab.begin_fill()
        ab.circle(300-x*n)
        ab.end_fill()
        ab.pu()
        ab.left(90)
        ab.fd(x)
        ab.right(90)

zielscheibe(10)
turtle.mainloop()
```