# How to increase the speed of a turtle program?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle 
turtle.bgcolor("black")
for i in range (15):
    for colours in ("red", "magenta", "blue", "cyan", "green", "yellow"):
        turtle.color(colours)
        turtle.pensize(3)
        turtle.left(4)
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(90)
```

I want the speed of the program to run faster than what is running at right now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7444.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up python's 'turtle' function and stop it freezing at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119991/how-to-speed-up-pythons-turtle-function-and-stop-it-freezing-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

Folks will answer this by saying use turtle's `speed()` method, preferably `speed('fastest')`, or use turtle's `tracer(0)` and `update()` methods.  (But not *both* `speed()` and `tracer()` as the latter makes the former a no-op.)

But let's *think outside the shell* and speed this up, faster than `speed('fastest')`) without using either approach:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from itertools import cycle

color = cycle(['red', 'magenta', 'blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow'])

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.register_shape('box', ((0, 0), (20, 0), (20, 20), (0, 20)))

turtle = Turtle(shape='box', visible=False)
turtle.shapesize(10, 10, 3)

def draw():
    turtle.pencolor(next(color))
    turtle.left(4)
    turtle.stamp()

    screen.ontimer(draw)

draw()

screen.mainloop()
```

Yes, it has its limitations.  ;-)