# how to increase the speed old a turtle program

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()

def curve():
    for i in range(200):
        pen.right(1)
        pen.forward(1)

def heart():
    pen.fillcolor('red')
    pen.begin_fill()
    pen.left(140)
    pen.forward(113)
    curve()
    pen.left(129)
    curve()
    pen.forward(112)
    pen.end_fill()

def txt():
    pen.up()
    pen.setpos(-68, 95)
    pen.down()
    pen.color('lightgreen')
    pen.write("Python", font=("Verdana", 18, "bold"))

heart()

txt()

pen.ht()
```

using turtle in this program
i want to increase speed

Comment: A very similar question was asked [just an hour prior to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74693468/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-a-turtle-program). Please search the site and the docs--this question has shown up many times before and there are clear answers out there you can use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try using this:

```
turtle.speed(0)
#your code here
```

Comment: Consider explaining how this solution increases speed